# Is it possible to save video from VideoView in Android?

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

In Android Studio there is a VideoView that can play a video from a URL. It works fine and I know when it starts to work, start to download and play it When it plays the video for the first time if you disconnect your internet connection (don't close your app) there is no need to download it again and you can play it again.

Now how can I access this file to save it on the storage(SD/Phone)?
Is it a file or cache? It seems the stream is caching somewhere. How can to access it programmatically?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can save video with URI.

```
void savefile(URI sourceuri)
{
    String sourceFilename= sourceuri.getPath();
    String destinationFilename = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+File.separatorChar+"abc.mp3";

    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

    try {
      bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFilename));
      bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destinationFilename, false));
      byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
      bis.read(buf);
      do {
        bos.write(buf);
      } while(bis.read(buf) != -1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      try {
        if (bis != null) bis.close();
        if (bos != null) bos.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```